# Is there a way to append duplicate rows in DataFrame to right hand side as new columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains rows with duplicates in one column, but different values in the other columns. I need to combine these duplicate rows whilst retaining the values from each row. See below example with duplicate values in the 'ID' column.

```
data={'ID':['01.560','05.890','05.890','02.564'],'Foo':[1,4,7,6],'Ba':['cat','dog','rabbit','monkey'],'Bar':[5.76,9.99,1.20,7.19]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)


output:
       ID  Foo      Ba   Bar
0  01.560    1     cat  5.76
1  05.890    4     dog  9.99
2  05.890    7  rabbit  1.20
3  02.564    6  monkey  7.19
```

What I need is the rows with duplicate ID moved to the right with new columns (probably with some prefix to ensure col names are unique). The desired output is:

```
        Foo      Ba   Bar  Foo1  Ba1  Bar1
ID                       
01.560    1     cat  5.76  NaN   NaN   NaN
05.890    4     dog  9.99  7  rabbit  1.20
02.564    6  monkey  7.19  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I have tried appending the duplicate rows to a dict, then producing a new dataframe from that dict, and appending to the original dataframe. However this method is very slow, and was wondering if there is a more straightforward way of achieving this.

```
def singl_line(ID,df):    
    line_num = 1
    results=dict()
    for i in range(len(df.loc[df['ID'] == ID])):
        fll=df.to_dict('records')[df.loc[df['ID'] == ID].index[i]]
        numbered=dict(("{} {}".format(k,line_num),v) for k,v in fll.items())
        line_num+=1
        results.update(numbered)
        continue
    return results
df_1ln=pd.DataFrame()
full=df['ID'].tolist()
nodup = [] 
for i in full: 
    if i not in nodup: 
        nodup.append(i)
    continue
nodup

for i in nodup:
    temp=pd.DataFrame([singl_line(i,df)],columns=singl_line(i,df).keys())
    df_1ln=df_1ln.append(temp,sort=False)
    continue
df_1ln

output:
     ID 1  Foo 1    Ba 1  Bar 1    ID 2  Foo 2    Ba 2  Bar 2
0  01.560      1     cat   5.76     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN
0  05.890      4     dog   9.99  05.890    7.0  rabbit    1.2
0  02.564      6  monkey   7.19     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN
```

The dataset i am working with has ~4000 rows and 150 columns with about 10 duplicates for each ID, so i am looking for a method which is faster than the one above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way using `pivot` (you will have to re-organize the columns though):

```
result = (df.assign(count=df.groupby("ID").cumcount())
            .pivot(index='ID', columns='count'))

result.columns = ["_".join(str(x) for x in i) for i in result.columns]

print (result)

        Foo_0  Foo_1    Ba_0    Ba_1  Bar_0  Bar_1
ID                                                
01.560    1.0    NaN     cat     NaN   5.76    NaN
02.564    6.0    NaN  monkey     NaN   7.19    NaN
05.890    4.0    7.0     dog  rabbit   9.99    1.2
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly. My previous method was taking over an hour to process, this method is almost instant :)

Answer (score 1):

A self-join would work well, answered below & in this question:
[self-join with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434723/self-join-with-pandas)

```
df.join(df.drop('ID', 1), on='ID', rsuffix='1')
```

Comment: I am getting below error while trying to do self join.''ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat""

Answer (score 0):

This solves your request; u will have to test it and see if it scalable

```
M = df.loc[df.duplicated('ID')].add_suffix('_1').set_index('ID_1')

orig = df.drop_duplicates('ID').set_index('ID')

pd.concat([orig,M],axis=1)

        Foo Ba       Bar    Foo_1   Ba_1    Bar_1
 01.560 1   cat     5.76    NaN     NaN     NaN
 05.890 4   dog     9.99    7.0     rabbit  1.2
 02.564 6   monkey  7.19    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

get the dataframe of duplicated values and concatenate with the dataframe of duplicate free values, on the columns axis. Note that the index is set to 'ID'