# How to apply Self Join on Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, left-join, self-join

I am stuck basically joining a Pandas series with a DataFrame.

Let's generate some dummy data using code below

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05',
                              '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-10',
                              '2021-01-11', '2021-01-12', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-14'],
                     'New_Date': [np.nan, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-03',
                                    '2021-01-06', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-08', '2021-01-09', '2021-01-11',
                                    '2021-01-11', '2021-01-13', '2021-01-13', np.nan],
                     'Price': [1, 1, 5, 3, 4, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7]})
test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['Date'])
test['New_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['New_Date'])
test.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

**Actual Df**

```
+------------+------------+-------+
|    Date    |  New_Date  | Price |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 01/01/2021 | NaT        |     1 |
| 02/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 |     1 |
| 03/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 |     5 |
| 04/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |     3 |
| 05/01/2021 | 03/01/2021 |     4 |
| 06/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |     3 |
| 07/01/2021 | 08/01/2021 |     2 |
| 08/01/2021 | 08/01/2021 |     5 |
| 09/01/2021 | 09/01/2021 |     6 |
| 10/01/2021 | 11/01/2021 |     4 |
| 11/01/2021 | 11/01/2021 |     3 |
| 12/01/2021 | 13/01/2021 |     2 |
| 13/01/2021 | 13/01/2021 |     1 |
| 14/01/2021 | NaT        |     7 |
+------------+------------+-------+
```

**Desired Output**

```
+------------+------------+-------+-----------+
|    Date    |  New_Date  | Price | New_Price |
+------------+------------+-------+-----------+
| 01/01/2021 | NaT        |     1 | NaN       |
| 02/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 |     1 | 1         |
| 03/01/2021 | 01/01/2021 |     5 | 1         |
| 04/01/2021 | 04/01/2021 |     3 | 3         |
| 05/01/2021 | 03/01/2021 |     4 | 5         |
| 06/01/2021 | 06/01/2021 |     3 | 3         |
| 07/01/2021 | 08/01/2021 |     2 | 5         |
| 08/01/2021 | 08/01/2021 |     5 | 5         |
| 09/01/2021 | 09/01/2021 |     6 | 6         |
| 10/01/2021 | 11/01/2021 |     4 | 3         |
| 11/01/2021 | 11/01/2021 |     3 | 3         |
| 12/01/2021 | 13/01/2021 |     2 | 1         |
| 13/01/2021 | 13/01/2021 |     1 | 1         |
| 14/01/2021 | NaT        |     7 | NaN       |
+------------+------------+-------+-----------+
```

I want to create a column `New_Price` by using `New_Date` as an index and Joining with `Date` to get `Price` which will be named as `New_Price`.

As per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41434723/self-join-with-pandas)

I've tried the solution below:

```
test['New_Price'] = test['Price'][test['New_Date']].values
```

The above solution fails due to `NaT`, this is not basically an actual join so I tried an another way

```
test.join(test.drop('New_Date', 1), on='New_Date', rsuffix='_y')
```

This solves the problem as I just need to rename `Price_y` to `New_Price` but **if there are 20 columns** in test df how can I keep columns from left df and only price column named as `New_Price` which would come from right df. Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) only on the `Price` column aligned on `New_Date`:

```
new_df = test.join(test['Price'].rename('New_Price'), on='New_Date')
```

`new_df`

```
             New_Date  Price  New_Price
Date                                   
2021-01-01        NaT      1        NaN
2021-01-02 2021-01-01      1        1.0
2021-01-03 2021-01-01      5        1.0
2021-01-04 2021-01-04      3        3.0
2021-01-05 2021-01-03      4        5.0
2021-01-06 2021-01-06      3        3.0
2021-01-07 2021-01-08      2        5.0
2021-01-08 2021-01-08      5        5.0
2021-01-09 2021-01-09      6        6.0
2021-01-10 2021-01-11      4        3.0
2021-01-11 2021-01-11      3        3.0
2021-01-12 2021-01-13      2        1.0
2021-01-13 2021-01-13      1        1.0
2021-01-14        NaT      7        NaN
```

Comment: Good trick and also adhere to the question title!  +1

Comment: Thanks @SeaBean :) likewise `map` is a great approach.

Answer (score 3):

As the dataframe `test` has already set `Date` as an index, you can readily use it as a mapping table for looking up `New Date` from index `Date`. Then, based on the matching `New_Date` to `Date`, we can get the corresponding  `Price` as `New_Price` (for `New_Date`).

This can be achieved by using [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), as follows:

```
test['New_Price'] = test['New_Date'].map(test['Price'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(test)

             New_Date  Price  New_Price
Date                                   
2021-01-01        NaT      1        NaN
2021-01-02 2021-01-01      1        1.0
2021-01-03 2021-01-01      5        1.0
2021-01-04 2021-01-04      3        3.0
2021-01-05 2021-01-03      4        5.0
2021-01-06 2021-01-06      3        3.0
2021-01-07 2021-01-08      2        5.0
2021-01-08 2021-01-08      5        5.0
2021-01-09 2021-01-09      6        6.0
2021-01-10 2021-01-11      4        3.0
2021-01-11 2021-01-11      3        3.0
2021-01-12 2021-01-13      2        1.0
2021-01-13 2021-01-13      1        1.0
2021-01-14        NaT      7        NaN
```